# PFsense captive portal images are not appearing

Tags: html, pfsense, captiveportal

I uploaded a captive portal html page and it is redirecting correctly to the specified page. However it is not displaying the images included in the html page although I uploaded those images to the file manager and I changed their names in the html page according to the new names given by the file manager. But it still not appearing when I click in view button.
Could you help me? Am I missing any thing??

Answer (score 0):

See this:
I create a HTML page for captive portal, my page include 1 image named:  logo.png...
i load "logo.png to "File Manager" on pfsense, but, in the upload, pfsense rename the image to: "captiveportal-logo.png".
the trouble is the renames on files from PfSense.
(in my case detect this)